# Site Stats on front page lists -179% Answered questions

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image: Answered listed as -179%]

I noticed this this morning while browsing old questions. I think this is a little... off.
Answered appears to be accurate in Area 51.

After jumping around to a few other beta sites, this appears to be a common bug.

It appears this is [also posted in the SO meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125117/incorrect-answer-rate-being-displayed), and it's been marked completed. So, would a mod like to mark this completed? (Or just delete it since it's not relevant anymore; not sure what procedure is.)

Comment: I believe it accounts for all future questions based on current ratios.

Comment: Currently, this appears to be behaving again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just converted some internal code over from v1 of our [API](http://api.stackexchange.com) to v2.  This conversion caused a bug with this stat that has since been fixed.  Everything should be good to go now.